# How to convert a HTTP stream to HTTPS?

Tags: node.js, ssl, nginx, https, mixed-content

My website is running via HTTPS at a public hoster and connects to a node server that is running on a Raspberry PI.

There is also a piece of hardware (lets call it decoder) in the same network with the PI which sends a data stream via TCP. The purpose of the PI is to read that stream and send it via `WebSocket` to the browser. So the goal is to output that stream on my website.

Now I'm running in a mixes content problem and have no idea how to solve it.

What I have done so far is to install an `nginx` webserver on the PI and have installed a Letsencrypt certificate. Both are running fine (tested via normal https:// call in a webbrowser).

The Websocket connection **without** SSL works fine as well and I get the data, but **with** SSL wont work. I guess that the problem is, that the decoder is not able to handle SSL.

So how can I "send", "convert", "tunnel" or "proxy" the non-SSL data stream to a HTTPS server?

**Update**

@Jake Holzinger: you are absolutely right. The given information was not enough. Sorry! I try to clarify:

1. `nginx` is without any further modification. So it is the configuration which comes from the installation
2. the website (Angular) does a `let connection = new WebSocket('wss://domain:port');`
3. The node server looks like follows:

   ```
   const net = require('net');
   const fs = require('fs');
   const https = require('https');
   const date = require('date-and-time');
   const config = require('./server-config.json');
   const httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

   //  SSL SERVER
   try {
       const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/' + config.DNSROUTER + '/privkey.pem', 'utf8');
       const certificate = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/' + config.DNSROUTER + '/cert.pem', 'utf8');
       const ca = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/' + config.DNSROUTER + '/chain.pem', 'utf8');

       const options = {
               key: privateKey,
               cert: certificate,
               ca: ca
       };

       let proxy = httpProxy.createServer({
           target: 'ws://localhost:9030',
           ssl: {
               key: privateKey,
               cert: certificate
           }
       }).listen(9031);
   }
   catch (e) {
       console.log("LETSENCRYPT certificates not found! No SSL!");
       console.log(e)
   }

   /**
    *  server
    */
   let connections = {};
   let WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;

   // start WS via HTTP
   const wss1 = new WebSocketServer({port: 9030});

   wss1.on('connection', function(ws) {
       CLIENTS.push(ws);
       console.log('connection via HTTP');

       ws.on('close', function () {
           console.log('close HTTP!');
           CLIENTS = CLIENTS.filter(item => item != ws);
       })
   })


   /**
    *  client
    */
   let connect = function() {

                   console.log(now(), 'Starting server...');

                   const socket = net.createConnection({ port: config.PORT, host: config.HOST }, () => {
                       console.log('Connected to server!');
                   })

                   socket.on('connect', () => {
                       console.log(now(), 'Connected to server!');

                       socket.on('data', data => {
                           sendAll(data);
                       });
                   });

                   socket.on('error', data => {
                       console.log(now(), "Connnection refused:", data.errno,data.code,"(IP:", data.address + ":" + data.port + ")");

                       setTimeout(() => {
                           socket.removeAllListeners();

                           console.log(now(),"Reconnecting...");
                           connect();
                       }, 1000);
                   });

                   socket.on('end', () => {
                       console.log(now(), 'Disconnected from server');
                       console.log(now(), "Reconnecting...");

                       socket.removeAllListeners();
                       connect();
                   });
   }

   connect();
   ```

I hope that this will get a better impression. Thx for your help!

Comment: Does the client (web browser) attempt to create a secure websocket connection (`wss://`) when you are browsing over a secure connection (`https://`)? Can you provide your NGINX configuration? Can you share your server code? There is not enough information here to provide a detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Now I solved this issue in a different way.

Instead of creating a proxy server node implementation, I've have created the reverse-proxy on `nginx` webserver level to proxy all HTTPS -> HTTP calls to the PI. The code below is working fine for me now.

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

and change the content like this:

```
server {
    listen 9031 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/DOMAIN_DNS/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/DOMAIN_DNS/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9030;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_read_timeout 86400;
    }
}
```